# How to add multiple ActionListeners for multiple buttons in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I know how to create one button and an Action Listener for it. But I want to have several buttons and actionListeners for them doing separate actions unrelated to each other.

Example:

```
protected JButton x;

x = new JButton("add");
x.addActionListener(this);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { //code.....}
```

Now I want to have other buttons which may hav different functions like subtract, multiply etc.
please suggest. thanks

Comment: don't use ActionListener, use Action instead: the general rule for it is to always go for the highest abstraction available

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What about:

```
    JButton addButton = new JButton( new AbstractAction("add") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            // add Action
        }
    });

    JButton substractButton = new JButton( new AbstractAction("substract") { 
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            // substract Action
        }
    });
```

Comment: +1 for all the answers. @oliholz Nice example of use of Actions.

Comment: thanks a lot. I was looking for this for past  days and couldnt find it.

Comment: This code gives me an error at ```JButton(new AbstractAction(){})```, method is undefined.

Comment: @FrasherGray Please provide the complete error lineand your java version. Do you use `import javax.swing.JButton;` an `import javax.swing.AbstractAction`?

Answer (score 11):

Use inner classes:

```
x = new JButton("add"); 
x.addActionListener(
  new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      //your code here
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 7):

how about...

```
protected JButton x, z, a, b,c;

x = new JButton("add x");
z = new JButton("add z");
a = new JButton("add a");
b = new JButton("add b");
c = new JButton("add c");
x.addActionListener(this);
z.addActionListener(this);
a.addActionListener(this);
b.addActionListener(this);
c.addActionListener(this);
```

then

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
     if (evt.getSource()==x)
         {
            //do something
         }
     else if (evt.getSource()==z)
         {
            //do something
         }
     else if (evt.getSource()==a)
         {
            //do something
         }
     else if (evt.getSource()==b)
         {
            //do something
         }
     else if (evt.getSource()==c)
         {
            //do something
         }
}
```

this is always works for me, but honestly I'm not sure if it's not bad practice

Comment: evt.getSource() wasn't working for me but evt.getActionCommand() worked.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7510013/11860907

Answer (score 6):

You can either use `ActionEvent.getSource()` to decide the source and act accordingly or you can define different `ActionListeners` for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create new instance of the `ActionListener` each time. 
BTW for lots of reasons it is recommended to use `Action`'s instead.

Here is nice resource which also explains why you should go with using Actions over ActionListeners, a Java tutorial titled [How to Use Actions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

**EDIT**: @fmucar is right you can do it all in a single ActionListener. Though having separate functional Actions allows you to reuse them independently.

Answer (score 1):

You can create different action listener instances, not using your class:

```
x.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    { ... }
});
```

There are several other methods to create action listener, just like any class, but for short actions this (anonymous class) is a convenient way.