# How can I find out which button was clicked?

Tags: java, swing, button, actionlistener

I've got my buttons working right, and I'm a listener to each button like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 25; ++i) {
    buttons[i] = new Button(Character.toString(letters[i]));
    buttons[i].addActionListener(actionListener);
    panel1.add(buttons[i]);
}
```

Here as you can see the listener is called, and I want to find out which button I'm clicking. Is there a way to do that?

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println(actionEvent.getSource());
    }
};
```

I need some way to find the button in the array.

Comment: cast first the source to button, then get the label ((Button)actionEvent.getSource()).getLabel() ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this

```java
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println(actionEvent.getActionCommand());
    }
};
```

Comment: wow thank you very much java sure has alot of stuff but some functions are awesome

Comment: Try [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#method_summary) (then follow the links to the classes from which `ActionEvent` inherits and also check the methods of those).  The JavaDocs - very handy for this sort of stuff.  ;)

Answer (score 7):

In order to get label, try this.

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener()
{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            JButton button = (JButton)actionEvent.getSource();
            String label = button.getLabel(); //Deprecated 

            String label2 = button.getText();
     }
};
```

Comment: Where should I add this code? I would like it to work for my all buttons.

Answer (score 6):

ActionEvent has a method getActionCommand() that will get a JButton's actionCommand String. This is usually it's text as well (for JButtons).

Comment: +1 for mentioning `getActionCommand()` but especially for *"This is **usually** it's text as well"*  (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 0):

```java
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    l1.setText("");//name of level what you want

    t1.setText(null);//text field what you want 

    t2.setText(null);//text field what you want
}
```

Comment: I don't know whose question you are answering, but it does not seem to be the question asked by Makenshi.